# How to disable "achievement" pop-ups?

Tags: notifications, google-play-games

When I'm playing a game, sometimes Google Play Games gives a pop-up at the top of the screen notifying me of a an "achievement". How do I disable this? The settings have checkboxes for notifications for "multiplayer", "missions" and "requests" but not for "achievements".

Comment: Try doing this in Google Settings app?

Comment: @xavier_fakerat That shows exactly the same settings as the Google Play Games app

Comment: I think I managed to disable this by going to Settings -> Apps -> Google Play Games -> Notification -> Off

Comment: @bdforbes Had no effect

Comment: That's unfortunate... I'll play a game at some point today and see if I still get achievement notifications.